# Where do I add code to capitalize the first letter in the first word?

Tags: java

```
//Author: Kathleen Gutierrez
//Name: CS123Ass3ID0121.java

import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CS123Ass3ID0121{

  public static void main(String[]args){
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);



    System.out.println("Please enter a line of text with no punctuation:");
    String sentence = keyboard.nextLine();

    String [] words = sentence.split(" ");
    String output= words[words.length - 1];

    for(int i=1; i < words.length - 1; i++){
    output += " " + words[i];
    }
    System.out.println(output + " " + words[0]);          
  }
}
```

I am inputting "one two three four five six seven"
my output needs to be "Seven two three four five six one"

Comment: We are not a code writing service. What don't you understand about what you are doing? What don't you understand about what you have to do? Have you looked into String manipulation techniques?

Comment: I obviously written my code. I have looked into string manipulation, I am simply asking where do I input toUpperCase() at to make the S in seven capitalize. I am not asking for someone to write me code.

Comment: Having to manually type in "one two three four five six seven" is a bit of a pain. Can't paste it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add it when you initialize `output`, since it's initialized with the last `String`, and that `String` is what you are modifying:

```
String output = Character.toString(words[words.length - 1].charAt(0)).toUpperCase()
            + words[words.length - 1].substring(1);
```

- [`toUpperCase()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase%28%29): converts a `String` to uppercase
- [`charAt(i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28char%29): get character at index `i`
- [`Character.toString(c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#toString%28char%29): converts character `c` into a `String`(so you can apply `toUpperCase()` method)

Comment: Thank you very much, these are great tips. Noted them down. It worked perfectly!